# How to calculate a z-index?

Tags: algorithm, tree

I can't seem to figure myself an unique z-index for my custom tree structure considering that each node has it's absolute level and it's absolute index withhin it's direct parent.

Any idea how to calculate such one uniquely for each node without the need to recalculate it for others when inserting / removing (except if the node's index changes, of course).

Comment: What have you done so far? give us some code and your initial strategy?

Comment: Nothing to be honest, I have no clue where to start from except iterating the whole tree every time and calculating a loop-index variable..

Comment: You need to calculate the height of each node, or the inverse?  What's level 0: the root or the lowest leaf?

Comment: Level 0 is the root, yes. I'm just trying to find a way to calculate the absolute index of a node within the whole tree without the need to recalculate the whole tree again for each insertion/removal